# Get OS version on OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, unix, ubuntu

I have an old script which I use to run in Ubuntu.
Now, I have a Mac and want to reuse the script.

Does anyone know what would be equivalent of the following commands in Mac OS?

```
def runCmd(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                         shell=True, 
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         close_fds=True)
    result=p.stdout.readlines()
    s=result[0].split()[0]
    return s

def getKernelVer():
    cmd="uname -r| cut --delim=\'.\' -f1-2"
    return runCmd(cmd)

def getUbuntuVer():
    cmd="lsb_release  -a | grep Release | cut -f 2"
    return runCmd(cmd)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uname -r` works identically under Darwin. The kernel version isn't something that most people talk or care about, but it's there. Only gotcha is that `cut` doesn't support the `--delim` long option, so, try this instead:

```
uname -r | cut -d. -f1-2
```

Kernel versioning is quite different for Darwin than for Linux, though, so the purpose of running `cut` here is unclear. (In fact, it's not quite clear on Linux either, as the versioning scheme changed significantly with the release 3.0.)

To get the current version of Mac OS (roughly equivalent to the "release" you're getting for Ubuntu), you can use the command:

```
sw_vers -productVersion
```

Comment: I get an error on "cut" part on kernel version
uname -r| cut --delim=\'.\' -f1-2
cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]

Comment: Whoops, missed that. See edit, or just drop the `cut` part entirely.

Comment: I would use `sw_vers -productVersion` for the second requirement, people at Apple like to move things around.

Comment: @mmgp: Ooh, nice find! I wasn't aware of `sw_vers`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the python "platform" module (i've no access to Ubuntu, pls try and post your finding :)

1. use platform.system() to distinguish between Linux or Darwin
2. call platform.release() to get kernel version
3. call platform.linux_distribution() or platform.mac_ver() to get vendor specific version number.

On CentOS:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 23 2013, 17:26:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>> platform.release()
'2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64'
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('CentOS', '6.4', 'Final')
>>>
```

On OS X:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Darwin'
>>> platform.release()
'13.0.0'
>>> platform.mac_ver()
('10.9', ('', '', ''), 'x86_64')
```